# What type of data is the number of correct answers

Tags: discrete-data

Hello everyone this is my first question here!
I want to study the relationship between gestational age, birth weight, etc and results on different language tests in very preterm infants. In order to choose the right stats test I need your help in determining if the following data is considered discrete.
In one of the tests the child is classified as having answered 0 out of 4 questions correctly, or 1 out of 4 questions correctly, or 2 out of 4 correctly, etc.

- 0 correct answers
- 1 correct answer
- 2 correct answers
- 3 correct answers
- 4 correct answers

Should I consider it as discrete data?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: It's a count. Do you have definitions for "discrete" and "interval"? When you say "interval" are you referring to Stevens' typology of scale (nominal/ordinal/interval/ratio), or do you mean that the variable is interval-valued?

Answer (score 1):

This question needs more clarifications. If you mean that you have a random variable that can take the values from 0 to 4, then it's clearly a discrete variable.

Comment: Could one not also advance an argument that (at least for certain kinds of analysis) it would be valid to consider this of "interval" type?  That means differences in values are meaningful and that any two equal differences represent the same quantity, so that the difference between a count of 2 and 0 is the same as the difference between 3 and 1, *etc*.

Comment: @whuber I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: It is likely the reference to "interval" refers to Stephens' typology of measurement.  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement) gives an overview, including a description of what "interval" means.